# How to save memory taking advantange of unused bits?

Tags: c, memory, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

Take the hypotetical case that I have four `unsigned char` variables, and for whatever reason, in all of those variables, I never use the last bit, so I have four bits that I can use for another thing, without the need of having an extra variable.

**e.g:** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/287r7.png). How to use those bits that are highlighted in red.

I think that I will have to use math with bitwise operators, but I don't know if there is any right or wrong way.

**Note:** I'm trying to do this in C, so if you use C in the example, I'll be very grateful, but I think that other languages won't differ so much from the C approach.

Comment: The sheer overhead of masking and shifting and orring would cost a lot of program memory and not save you simply using another byte in the system.  I dont know of a language that can do it by simply declaring some special variable/syntax, you would have to synthesize this with a lot of code.

Comment: even with bitfields in C if you want to use them as a single bit variable/flag it still generates overhead in .text that is not worth the savings on the .data/.bss side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general C provides an abstract machine (to hide the underlying details) and converts your code into something that may be radically different. For the C abstract machine; an `unsigned char` has `CHAR_BITS` bits (maybe not 8 bits), structures (including bitfields) may have any amount of extra padding (whatever the compiler felt like), etc.

If you care about the underlying details; then you have to break through the abstraction. In your case, this might mean (e.g.) using a `uint32_t` and doing shifting and masking yourself; so that you can have a guarantee that the compiler converts it into what you want.

Example (untested and relatively awful - could use defines and macros):

```
uint32_t demoPackedValue = ((uint32_t)'a' << 24) | ((uint32_t)'b' << 16) ((uint32_t)'c' << 8) | (uint32_t)'d';

char getChar1(uint32_t packedValue) {
    return packedValue & 0x0000007FUL;
}

uint32_t setChar1(uint32_t packedValue, char c) {
    packedvalue = (packedvalue & 0xFFFFFF80UL) | ((uint32_t)c);
    return packedvalue;
}

int getBit1(uint32_t packedValue) {
    return !!(packedValue & 0x00000080UL);
}

uint32_t setBit1(uint32_t packedValue, int value) {
     if(value == 0) {
         packedValue &= 0xFFFFFF7FUL;
     } else {
         packedValue |= 0x00000080UL;
     }
    return packedvalue;
}

char getChar2(uint32_t packedValue) {
    return (packedValue & 0x00007F00UL) >> 8;
}

uint32_t setChar2(uint32_t packedValue, char c) {
    packedvalue = (packedvalue & 0xFFFF80FFUL) | ((uint32_t)c << 8);
    return packedvalue;
}
```

Of course that's also likely to harm performance (unless you have a very large amount of data and the extra cost of shifting/masking can be justified).

Comment: But you can show me an example, ignoring the fact that it is a harm to the performance, please? Just to have the concept in mind.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo: OK :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do some bit shifting, but you wouldn't be getting much savings in terms of memory, and it would make your code harder to read and understand.

You can at least make this more transparent to your code by putting each of these values in a struct with bitfields:

```
struct vars {
    unsigned int var1:7;
    unsigned int var2:7;
    unsigned int var3:7;
    unsigned int var4:7;
    unsigned int extra:4;
};
```

Comment: (a) This results in `struct vars` using five bytes in Clang, GCC, and MSVC, so it does not accomplish the requested goal. (b) Using `unsigned char` for bit-field types is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 5 bytes was unexpected.  Changed field types to `unsigned int` which is standardized and results in a 4 byte struct in gcc.

Comment: Using `unsigned int` might achieve part of the expected result by virtue of "implementation defined accident" with no guarantee or assurance. Note that OP wanted "high bit of each byte" (not "group of 4 bits at the end") which is more likely to accidentally work (e.g. `unsigned int var1: 7; unsigned int spare1: 1; unsigned int var2: 7; unsigned int spare2: 1;` ,,,).